# PrimeFaces data table row count using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1. If there is any way to get DataTable row count and cell count using jquery becuase I try get row count and pass parameter to another function.I try below script but it not working.

```
1) alert("Rows = " + ($('#TestSubview:testForm:test table tbody tr:last').index() + 1));
2) var datatable=jQuery("#TestSubview:testForm:test");
alert(dataTable.tBodies[0].rows.length);

3)alert($('#'+dataTableId+' tbody tr').length);
```

Comment: Can you please add some html cod which you have tried? Or can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by using widgetVar variable of datatable :

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="datatable-styleClass"
            widgetVar="datatablewidget"
            ..........
            ..........
/>
```

load script after datatable rendered :

```
$(".datatable-styleClass").ready(function() {

   var rowCount = PF('datatablewidget').paginator.cfg.rowCount;
   alert(rowCount);

});
```

Comment: @Arul :  did you add script after <p:datatable> ?

Comment: Thanks,Now it working. Why can we add script after p:dataTable,Not work before add p:dataTable?

Comment: @Arul : because HTML elements for p:datatable is not generated yet if add script before p:datatable.

Comment: @Arul : if its working then mark as answer, so other can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, there is an attribute:

> "rowIndexVar - Name of iterator to refer each row index."

You just assign a var name for this

> rowIndexVar="rCount"

As for the column I think you can just assign a fixed column number per `<p:column>`

```
<p:dataTable value="#{Bean.test}" var="t" rowIndexVar="rCount">
    <p:column headerText="Count">                       
        <h:outputText value="#{rCount}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Value">
        <h:outputText value="#{t}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{Bean.test(rCount,3)}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{Bean.test(rCount,4)}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```